# Column alignment in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I need three images to be placed in the first row and two images in second row as shown in the below figure.
[image]

My code for the above image is as follows,

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:15%">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="F:\Project P\img\logo_homework.png" alt="Engg">
            </a>
            <p style="text-align:center">I'm a Graduate</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="F:\Project P\img\logo_homework.png" alt="Engg">
            </a>
            <p style="text-align:center">I'm a Post Graduate</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="F:\Project P\img\logo_homework.png" alt="Engg">
            </a>
            <p style="text-align:center">I'm a PhD Guy</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:20%">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="margin-left:20%">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="F:\Project P\img\logo_homework.png" alt="Engg">
            </a>
            <p style="text-align:center">I'm a Course taking one</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="F:\Project P\img\logo_homework.png" alt="Engg">
            </a>
            <p style="text-align:center">Others</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

But when I view it in mobile mode using chrome inspect element it is displayed as below

[image]

I know I have placed an extra `div` but if I don't place the `div` the fourth image is placed in the first row.

How can I get them aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/68kycb4g/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5"></div>
</div>
```